# Simple Project management/bug tracking app?

Tags: macos, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I was wondering if you guys know of any software that allows me to jot down notes in a project based environment, as well as enabling me to track bugs or other issues in OSX.  Basically, I have a lot of little projects on the go, and I would like to have one place where I can store and organize all their information.  I have done lots of research on issue tracking systems, but they all seem to be overkill for what I need. I essentially need just a single user desktop application were I can enter bugs for myself to view later.  So far I have basically been doing this with sticky notes/other such applications, but I think its time for a step up to an application that stores the history of bug fixes, open issues, etc.  Any ideas?  Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you mentioned desktop, but from reading your question I would recommend Trello http://www.trello.com.

Trello is really nice for keeping track of small to medium projects and does not take up all of your time when entering in steps.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  Trello is very nice, but I think I'm going to try out [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a freelance web developer working on multiple projects. Earlier I used to use small applications to keep track of project tasks. Now that the number of projects have increased, I've been using Microsoft Project Professional. The [project management](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en-us/project-management.aspx) software ensures that I can test, report, and track all my project tasks. This helps me be in sync with project progress.

Answer (score 0):

We were searching for a simple bug tracking solution too and found some pretty cool platforms like Instabug, BugSee, ... The problem was that they are pretty expensive, so we developed a new platform that's made for everyone. BugBattle.

https://www.bugbattle.io

It offers something that's called in-app bug tracking, which allows you to report bugs (+ all kinds of useful information like screenshots, meta data about devices, ...) directly within your app. It's super easy & fast to integrate. I takes about 2 minutes or so to integrate it within your websites, apps, webapps. Def. worth trying.

In addition we added features like the BugBattle Challenge, which enables you to basically fight against others in bug fixing challenges. Haha, it should be fun to fix bugs :)